# WSO2 Authenticating device don't stop

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

I use WSO2 EMM 2.2.0 but i have a problem with my device register.
I have download the wso2 agent app from "https://10.0.240.35:9443/emm-web-agent/enrollment" and i have install the app. I wrote  my serveur addres as "https://10.0.240.35:9443", my domain as "tec6.com", my username as "test" then my password. I tick BYOD and press register. Now my real problem start. The Authenticating period in very very very long and doesn't work. I don't have a error and my device doesn't get register. Someone can help me or have a advice ?

Comment: Could you try without the "https://" part from the server address? Just enter the IP and Port

Comment: I've already try but that doesn't work, I've also try without the Port. I think this is a configuration problem with the serveur. The Authenticating period doesn't stop and I don't have any errors. Only :Authenticating Please wait

Comment: Hi, Have you configured the server to enroll via mutual SSL authentication? If not I guess the port you are using is incorrect. remove the "https" part and use 9763 instead of 9443.

Comment: I do but im not 100 pourcent sure I do it right. Have you a good documentation for wso2 emm 2.2 mutual SSL authentication ? I have try with the 9763 port and that doesn't work, authenticating period still doesn't stop and don't have any errors

Comment: In the folder "/home/wso2emm-2.2.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps" i have a "api#device-mgt#android#v1.0" but i don't have "mdm-android-agent". It's looks like its the same folder but there is a difference ?